# How can I run concurrent trials using AX?

Tags: pytorch

According to the AX documentation (https://ax.dev/docs/api.html), under the Service API, it says that "trials might be evaluated in parallel." How can I achieve this?

I have 4 GPUs, and I'd like to evaluate 4 different sets of hyperparameters at a time (4 training at the same time).

```
from ax.service.ax_client import AxClient
from ax.utils.measurement.synthetic_functions import branin

ax = AxClient()
ax.create_experiment(
    name="branin_test_experiment",
    parameters=[
        {
            "name": "x1",
            "type": "range",
            "bounds": [-5.0, 10.0],
            "value_type": "float",
        },
        {
            "name": "x2",
            "type": "range",
            "bounds": [0.0, 10.0],
        },
    ],
    objective_name="branin",
    minimize=True,
)

for _ in range(15):
    parameters, trial_index = ax.get_next_trial()
    ax.complete_trial(trial_index=trial_index, raw_data=branin(parameters["x1"], parameters["x2"]))

best_parameters, metrics = ax.get_best_parameters()
```

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: @nbubis This might help: https://ax.dev/tutorials/raytune_pytorch_cnn.html. I followed the guide and just today got something up and working. I couldn't get parallel working without using Ray.